# Swift 4 @escaping type as parameter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have the following function which makes a `GET` request to the server. The problem is that I need to provide a specific `struct` of type `Codable` as a type for `@escaping`. 
Then I use the same type for the JSONDecoder to decode the data received from JSON to `Video` type.

How Can I provide a type as a parameter to this function. I want to provide for. ex a `USER` type or `CAR` type

```
    struct Video: Codable {
        var title: String
        var pretty_artists: String
        var yt_id: String
        var views: String
        var video_name: String
        var published: Published
        var result: Bool

        init(title: String = "", pretty_artists: String = "", yt_id: String = "", views: String = "", video_name: String = "", published: String = "", result: Bool = true) {
            self.title = title
            self.pretty_artists = pretty_artists
            self.yt_id = yt_id
            self.views = views
            self.video_name = video_name
            self.published = Published()
            self.result = result
        }
    }
```

//Another File

```
class XHR {

    // Video to be Dynamic
    func makeGetCall(todoEndpoint: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Video?, Error?) -> Void) {

        // code
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            let todo = try decoder.decode(Video.self, from: responseData)
            completionHandler(todo, nil)
        } catch {
            print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
            print(error)
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }

    }
   }
```

// Here I call my function "ViewController.swift"

```
    // Initial request
xhr.makeGetCall<XHR>(todoEndpoint: "https://kida.al/search/uh/onajr", { result, err  in
    if(result != nil) {
        self.ytPlayer.load(withVideoId: result!.yt_id, playerVars: self.playerVars)
        self.updateVideo(data: result!)
    }
})
```

Comment: So does your code work now?

Comment: My code works fine, But I want to reuse the same code. I want to use the same `makeGetCall` for other types

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you are attempting to do. You want the `Video?` parameter in `@escaping` changeable?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want  @paper1111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using generics. Just replace `Video` with a generic parameter what conforms to `Codable` protocol. And that should be it.

```
func makeGetCall<T>(todoEndpoint: String, completionHandler: @escaping (T?, Error?) -> Void) where T: Codable {
    // As step one, you need to do networking to fetch `responseData`

    // code
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    do {
        let todo = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: responseData)
        completionHandler(todo, nil)
    } catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Declare type after the first parameter.

```
makeGetCall(todoEndpoint: "/path/to/resource") { (video: Video?, error) in

}
```

**Your usage**

```
class XHR {

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

func makeGetCall<T>(todoEndpoint: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<T>) -> Void) where T: Codable {

    // code
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    do {
        let todo = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: responseData)
        completionHandler(.success(todo))
    } catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        print(error)
        completionHandler(.failure(error))
    }

}
}

// Initial request

let xhr = XHR()
xhr.makeGetCall(todoEndpoint: "https://kida.al/search/uh/onajr") { (result: XHR.Result<Video>) in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        // Ups, there is something wrong
        print(error)
    case .success(let video):
        // Sal goodman
        self.ytPlayer.load(withVideoId: video.yt_id, playerVars: self.playerVars)
        self.updateVideo(data: video)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `func makeGetCall<T: Codable>`

Comment: I just did the same! @Scriptable

Comment: @Scriptable he added `where T: Codable`

Comment: @Scriptable thats `Swift 3` syntax, scroll to the right, that should be the one used in Swift 4

Comment: How is that Swift 3 syntax? what, in your function above restricts the type to Codable types only?

Comment: @Scriptable scroll to the right on the code and you find `where T: Codable`. That is the swift 4 syntax.

Comment: @dirtydanee I get two warnings on the first line `...where T: Codable`

`Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'Decodable'` and `Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'Encodable'`

Comment: @rexhin use the function as i have posted, do not modify it with Scriptable's  suggestion.

Comment: @dirtydanee no I'm using yours now but I get these two warnings at this line `...where T: Codable`

Comment: oh I see, Check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179 under the heading: Type Constraint Syntax. it uses the syntax I used, here is their example: `func findIndex<T: Equatable>(of valueToFind: T, in array:[T]) -> Int?`

Comment: @Scriptable its ok, both is fine ;)

Comment: @rexhin do you have this `func makeGetCall<T: Codable>...` ?

Comment: Yes, The warnings went away but now I have Errors when I call this function: I call it like this: 

`xhr.makeGetCall<VideoModel.Video>(todoEndpoint: "https://kida.al/search/uh/onajr", completionHandler:{ result, err  in`

But I get this error: `Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function`

Comment: Can you please update the usage as I updated my question? Also full project is here https://gitlab.com/rexhin/ios-kida @dirtydanee

Comment: @rexhin added your usage. However, you must know, this is solving only the generic types of Codable. You must do network request to get your `responseData`.

Comment: Thanks, It works perfectly now. I need some info. Why do you think is better to use an enum Result to handle error and success. Whats wrong with my solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164352/discussion-between-dirtydanee-and-rexhin).

Answer (score -2):

you can create model class for any object you want from this json:

```
class User {
    let userId: String?
    let userName: String?

    init(jsondata: JSON?) {
        self.userId = jsondata?["user_id"].stringValue
        self.userName = jsondata?["user_name"].stringValue  
    }
}
```

then create object of this model:

```
func makeGetCall(todoEndpoint: String, completionHandler: @escaping (User?, Error?) -> Void) {

    // code
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    do {
        let todo = User(responsedata)
    } catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The op wants the one function to be reusable for any codable type in their application. so they pass the type in and it returns that type from the JSON. your solution just makes it specific to a user. Also it's best to use codable in swift 4 than manually parsing the JSON dictionary